# Is there a way to list keys in context.Context?

Tags: go

So, I have a context.Context(https://golang.org/pkg/context/) variable with me, is there a way I can list all the keys this variable holds?

Comment: Yes, with reflection.

Comment: @mkopriva would you please elaborate it? It seems to me that the `context.Context` does not provide an API for looking up keys.

Comment: @leafbebop You're correct it doesn't, if it did you would not need reflection. With reflection however you can inspect the internal structure that implements the Context interface including its fields, if there are any. So given this https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/context/context.go#L479-L482 you can do this https://play.golang.com/p/zGDb6ZkogSX

Comment: If you just want to see the keys (but not process them from code), just print the context like `fmt.Println(ctx)`: https://play.golang.org/p/lPaOTM-nV6b

Comment: Oh, I get it, thanks. But I should say, there is a chance of breaking your code if the `Contex` interface is not implemented by the standard library or if the standard library changes its implementation.

Comment: @leafbebop that applies to all cases where one uses reflection to inspect the unexported details about a type. The provided example is just that, an example, it has more problems than the ones you've pointed out and therefore it is not inteded to be used as a robust solution to the problem.

Comment: No there is no real way to list the keys, because context is an interface and it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 34):

It is possible to list the internals of context.Context using unsafe reflection and using that information to figure out the keys and/or see if the information you want is in the context.

There are some pitfall such as if the context implementation returns a hardcoded value for a key it wont show up here, and it can be quite unclear on how to actually access the values using keys.

This is nothing I run in production. But in my case I needed to be able to inspect the context.Context to understand better what information it contains.

```
func printContextInternals(ctx interface{}, inner bool) {
    contextValues := reflect.ValueOf(ctx).Elem()
    contextKeys := reflect.TypeOf(ctx).Elem()

    if !inner {
        fmt.Printf("\nFields for %s.%s\n", contextKeys.PkgPath(), contextKeys.Name())
    }

    if contextKeys.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < contextValues.NumField(); i++ {
            reflectValue := contextValues.Field(i)
            reflectValue = reflect.NewAt(reflectValue.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(reflectValue.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()

            reflectField := contextKeys.Field(i)

            if reflectField.Name == "Context" {
                printContextInternals(reflectValue.Interface(), true)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("field name: %+v\n", reflectField.Name)
                fmt.Printf("value: %+v\n", reflectValue.Interface())
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("context is empty (int)\n")
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
func Ping(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    printContextInternals(r.Context(), false)
    /* Prints
        Fields for context.valueCtx
        context is empty (int)
        field name: key
        value: net/http context value http-server
        field name: val
        value: &{Addr::20885 Handler:0xc00001c000 TLSConfig:0xc000001c80 ReadTimeout:0s ReadHeaderTimeout:0s WriteTimeout:0s IdleTimeout:0s MaxHeaderBytes:0 TLSNextProto:map[h2:0x12db010] ConnState:<nil> ErrorLog:<nil> BaseContext:<nil> ConnContext:<nil> disableKeepAlives:0 inShutdown:0 nextProtoOnce:{done:1 m:{state:0 sema:0}} nextProtoErr:<nil> mu:{state:0 sema:0} listeners:map[0xc00015a840:{}] activeConn:map[0xc000556fa0:{}] doneChan:<nil> onShutdown:[0x12e9670]}
        field name: key
        value: net/http context value local-addr
        field name: val
        value: [::1]:20885
        field name: mu
        value: {state:0 sema:0}
        field name: done
        value: 0xc00003c2a0
        field name: children
        value: map[context.Background.WithValue(type *http.contextKey, val <not Stringer>).WithValue(type *http.contextKey, val [::1]:20885).WithCancel.WithCancel:{}]
        field name: err
        value: <nil>
        field name: mu
        value: {state:0 sema:0}
        field name: done
        value: <nil>
        field name: children
        value: map[]
        field name: err
        value: <nil>
        field name: key
        value: 0
        field name: val
        value: map[]
        field name: key
        value: 1
        field name: val
        value: &{handler:0x151cf50 buildOnly:false name: err:<nil> namedRoutes:map[] routeConf:{useEncodedPath:false strictSlash:false skipClean:false regexp:{host:<nil> path:0xc0003d78f0 queries:[]} matchers:[0xc0003d78f0 [GET POST]] buildScheme: buildVarsFunc:<nil>}}

    */


    printContextInternals(context.Background(), false)
    /* Prints
        Fields for context.emptyCtx
        context is empty (int)
    */
}
```

Comment: This function was extremely helpful to me. SAML claims attributes were getting swallowed by the SAML package this helped me find them immediately.

Comment: @Robin this looks super helpful! But can someone please explain the `inner` parameter? It's not immediately obvious to me what it does.

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl it just prints the package name and struct name in the initial call ("Fields for context.valueCtx" in my example)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to list all the keys of `context.Context`. Because that type is just an interface. So what does this mean?

In general a variables can hold a concrete type or an interface. A variable with an interface type does not have any concrete type informations on it. So it would makes no difference if the interface is empty (`interface{}`) or context.Context. Because they could be a lot of different types which are implementing that interface. The variable does not have a concrete type. It is just something abstract.

If you use reflection you could observer the fields and all the methods of the type which is set to that variable (with interface type). But the logic how the method `Value(key interface{}) interface{}` is implemented is not fixed. It does not have to be a map. You could also make an implementation with slices, database, an own type of an hash table, ...

So there is no general way to list all the values.

Comment: "it makes no difference if it is interface{} or another interface" is really misleading. It makes a huge difference what interface type an interface value is. That's the whole point of defining interface types.